# Writing nodejs scripts inside nextjs HTML

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I am programing my new website in a structure with nodejs, nextjs and expressjs. The problem is tho that I want to write a if statement inside of the HTML part which in that case it will write the if statement as normal html on the website:

```
const Admin = () => (

  <AdminLayout>

  <style global jsx>
  {
  `body {
    background: #eff0f3;
   }`
  }
  </style>  
    <div className="jumbotron" style={jumbotron}>

      if (1=1) {
      <h3>Please select a tool first.</h3>
    } else {
      <h3>Something is wrong :/ .</h3>
    }

    </div>
  </AdminLayout>
)

export default Admin
```

And the out put is just:

**if (1=1)
Please select a tool first.
else
Something is wrong :/ .**

as HTML on the website. How would I do this but having the script actually being a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js uses React that allows you to write something called `jsx`, which is what you're calling the "HTML part". You can write JavaScript expressions in `jsx`, but they need to be wrapper in `{}` brackets. Otherwise any JS code will actually just be interpreted as a text string in the rendered HTML. Check out the React Docs for [Embedding Expressions in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx).

There's lots of ways to do [conditional rendering in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator).

Here's one way to rewrite your code using `{}` to embed an expression and the ternary operator:

```
const Admin = () => (
  <AdminLayout>
    <style global jsx>{`
      body {
        background: #eff0f3;
      }
    `}</style>  
    <div className="jumbotron" style={jumbotron}>
      {1 == 1 ? (
        <h3>Please select a tool first.</h3>
      ) : (
        <h3>Something is wrong :/ .</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  </AdminLayout>
)

export default Admin
```